# Firewall Blocked Port Remains Open

Tags: firewall, port, windows-firewall, open

I'm using Windows Firewall to block port 4643, however when I do a Open Port Scan 4643 is shown to be open.

Firewall rule settings are set to block connections on all profiles (Domain, Private & Public), IP scope is set to Any, this is an Inbound Rule.

Does anyone know why it would still show the port as open? Thanks.

Comment: Are you blocking inbound or outbound in the firewall?

Comment: Inbound. I'll add it to the question.

Comment: Perhaps you are running an app which opens the port? What does `netstat -an | findstr 4643` tell you?

Comment: Nope, it returns blank

Comment: How exactly are you scanning for open ports?  Have you tried more than one scanner?

Comment: I'm using one of the online scanners pentest-tools.com

Comment: TCP or UDP? if its UDP, and a flow was initiated outbound before the scan started, the port would appear to be open to a scanner, as UDP can't tell whether a datagram is part of a existing conversation. Port scanners often provide weird results when scanning ports that are involved in an existing communication (for instance nmap often shows them as "filtered" ports) and UDP makes that all the harder.

Comment: This is shown as TCP and is listed as Open.